Is it possible to play Chess.app in macOS's Terminal without the graphical interface?
By using the command open /System/Applications/Chess.app in the Terminal, the graphical interfaced macOS chess game launches.
But I was wondering if it was possible to play chess directly in macOS's Terminal without having to launch the graphical interface?
If yes, how? What is the command?

System used (fwiw): macOS Sequoia 15.0.1 (24A348)

Yes, but don't ask me how it works:
/System/Applications/Chess.app/Contents/Resources/sjeng.ChessEngine

Update: In the same folder as the engine are some data files that appear to be opening books and a sample configuration file. Those need to be copied to your home folder (I assume) in order to use them.

You type the algebraic notation of the square you're going from and to, e.g. e2e4.

Might be better to repost/update the answer under the older question, so people finding either one will also find your answer.
